# Json Rpc Http getTransaction returns Parse Error

Tags: rpc, jsonrpc-api

I want to get a transaction via json rpc http method. I make a web request for a finilazed transaction, but i get -37200 Parse error.
I use C# to make web request.

```
 {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":"getTransaction",
        "params":["3bS5TJbuLSCpYSMufG2wR6ESqBavBkmGiRbJP75mHJJYV8hsB44ETq8CcvGXizosFjkwbwPihbbcHchnsDTJQ1vX",
    "json"]}
```

Result

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error"},"id":null}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very strange... this currently works:

```
$ curl https://api.devnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
                   {
                     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                     "id": 1,
                     "method": "getTransaction",
                     "params": [
                       "3bS5TJbuLSCpYSMufG2wR6ESqBavBkmGiRbJP75mHJJYV8hsB44ETq8CcvGXizosFjkwbwPihbbcHchnsDTJQ1vX",
                       "json"
                     ]
                   }
                 '
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"blockTime":1678194519,"meta":{"computeUnitsConsumed":0,"err":null,"fee":16000,"innerInstructions":[],"loadedAddresses":{"readonly":[],"writable":[]},"logMessages":["Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]","Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success","Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]","Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success","Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]","Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success"],"postBalances":[1187928720,2140000000,1,0,1],"postTokenBalances":[],"preBalances":[1197944720,2130000000,1,0,1],"preTokenBalances":[],"rewards":[],"status":{"Ok":null}},"slot":200363796,"transaction":{"message":{"accountKeys":["8DPC5MuznFSecgvTg4Cx5uhjYBeycsRM4DBoDtjySuZz","8X5zHADZ4oTZXC59JmjVn1NRqcA6DGc649TrwL11ZdNr","ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111","Fc7aCzx4uVaaFAU8RqYRQXwpdi3sR67b3rvuT9wuq2rR","11111111111111111111111111111111"],"header":{"numReadonlySignedAccounts":0,"numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts":3,"numRequiredSignatures":1},"instructions":[{"accounts":[],"data":"3qj9FXZR9T5q","programIdIndex":2},{"accounts":[],"data":"Fj2Eoy","programIdIndex":2},{"accounts":[0,1,3],"data":"3Bxs4NN8M2Yn4TLb","programIdIndex":4}],"recentBlockhash":"9eJvAiqrPmqQBLQrkcRebaCimjmBR3hUzU11zErVZZfL"},"signatures":["3bS5TJbuLSCpYSMufG2wR6ESqBavBkmGiRbJP75mHJJYV8hsB44ETq8CcvGXizosFjkwbwPihbbcHchnsDTJQ1vX"]}},"id":1}
```

Perhaps you were querying a node running a version older than 1.14, which may not properly parse the transaction. Can you be sure that your node is up to date?

Comment: I've changed the my web client that i do the post request. And it worked as usual